# XSLT - render a node value as HTML UI (not display the non-escaped HTML script)

Tags: c#, html, xslt, escaping, webbrowser-control

Environment - Dot Net 4.0, C#, XSLT, IE11, WebBrowser Control

I have an XSLT which processes a node with content that is an escaped HTML...

```
"&lt;b&gt;Hellow World&lt;/b&gt;"
```

I have a WebBrowser control that displays the transformed HTML fro the XSLT.
I have used `<xsl:value-of .. disable-output-escaping="yes">` it displays the unescaped value of the HTML text with actual `<b> & </b>` tags.

I want to **render the bold text** and not show the unescaped HTML script that makes the bold label.

Below line displays unescpaed HTML code whereas I actually want to **DISPLAY / RENDER THE HTML UI**

```
<xsl:value-of select="orderDetails/HTMLData" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

**EDIT**

I am applying XSLT transformation using C# code and displaying the output on a page on IE11/Chrome.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="assetTypeText" ></xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <table border="1" class="mainTable">

      <!--Header-->
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMainHeader">
          <xsl:value-of select="$assetTypeText" /> - <xsl:value-of select="//order/execOrderID/entityOID"></xsl:value-of>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <!--Client Information-->
      <tr class="trMain">
        <table class="InnerMainTable" >
          <tr>
            <td class="tdH2" colspan="2" >Client Information:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="tdH4">
              <table align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td class="tdInnerTableHeader">DESI</td>
                  <td class="tdInnerTableHeader">ACCOUNT</td>
                 <td class="tdInnerTableHeader">Markup Type</td>
                  <td class="tdInnerTableHeader">Markup</td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="//allocation">
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tdInnerTableValue" style="width:20%">
                      <xsl:value-of select="clientDetails/clientID" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdInnerTableValue" style="width:20%">
                      <xsl:value-of select="clientDetails/accountID" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdInnerTableValue" style="width:20%">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="charges/charge/chargeFormula" mode="enum"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdInnerTableValue" style="width:20%">
                      <xsl:value-of select="charges/charge/chargeRate" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </tr>

      <!--Security Details-->
      <tr class="trMain11">
        <table class="InnerMainTable" border="0">
          <tr class="trMain11">
            <td class="tdH2" >Security Details</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="trMain11">
            <td colspan="2" class="tdH4">
              <table align="left" class="InnerSecurityTable">
                <tr>
                  <td class="tdSecurityHeaders" style="width:20%">Asset Class:</td>
                  <td class="tdSecurityValue" style="width:80%">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$assetTypeText" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </tr>

      <!--Order Details-->
      <tr> 
        <table class="InnerMainTable" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="tdH2" colspan="2">Order Details</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdInnerOrderDetailsTableValue" colspan="2" >
              <!--Replace this DIV with current template-->
              <div class="TemplateDiv" id="content">
                <xsl:value-of select="orderDetails/HTMLData" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

**C# Code to transform**

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream configStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(Xslt); //Fetching XSLT File Location from config
XmlTextReader configReader = new XmlTextReader(configStream);
myXslTrans.Load(configReader); //Reading XSLT File
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(myXml); //this contains the embedded HTML Code ... orderDetails/HTMLData
XmlReader inputXmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(inputStream);
MemoryStream memOutputStream = new MemoryStream();

//Perform Transformation
myXslTrans.Transform(inputXmlReader, new XsltArgumentList(), memOutputStream);
memOutputStream.Flush();
memOutputStream.Position = 0;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memOutputStream);
sb.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
MyWebBrowserControl.NavigateToString(sb.ToString()); //Displays the HTML Content
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using XSLT inside the browser? Mozilla browsers like Firefox don't support disable-output-escaping. You will need to explain in more detail how you run the XSLT and where you display its result.

Comment: I have updated the XSLT I am trying to render the external HTML UI in...

Comment: Please show the C# code you use to run the transformation. Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use as you say you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: C# code added ... its a standard C# DotNet 4.0 code to perform XSLT Transformation ... Disregard XSLT 2.0 ... it was added by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, using `XslCompiledTransform` and a StringWriter to capture the results; the XML sample I have used is

```
<root>
  <html>&lt;b&gt;Hello World&lt;/b&gt;</html>
</root>
```

the XSLT sample is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="html">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the C#/.NET 4.0 code is

```
        XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();

        proc.Load("XSLTFile1.xslt");

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            proc.Transform("XMLFile1.xml", null, sw);
            wb1.NavigateToString(sw.ToString());
        }
```

where that code is inside an of a WPF button's click handler and wb1 is a WebBrowser control, it renders "Hello Word" as a bold text.

Comment: Can you print this HTML on a C# WebBrowser control? Does it render the UI?

Comment: Well in that case `disable-output-escaping` does not work differently but I would of course remove the template creating the `html` and `body` element so use `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="html">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
`. Result then is `<html><body><b>Hello World</b></body></html>`.

Comment: Is that `WebBrowser` control in a Windows Forms application or a WPF application? Why don't you provide all details in your question allowing us to see, understand and reproduce what you have tried?

Comment: I had specified that in my code earlier `MyWebBrowserControl.NavigateToString(sb.ToString()); //Displays the HTML Content` ... sorry for not being clear... That is why the title of the main question is about rendering not **printing** the HTML code.  I have edited my post and added more tags.

Comment: I have now put my code into a WPF sample app with a WebBrowser control, that renders a bold "Hello World".

Comment: I see that your code works... but strangely mine still prints the HTML code... I guess there is some other issue... But thanks a lot to give full support and have patience with this situation.